# How to properly import python modules from an adjacent folder?

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow Learn Python the Hard Way to teach myself python. I want to use the directory structure described in [Exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html), which for my question I'll simplify down to this:

```
bin/
    app.py
data/
    __init__.py
    foobar.py
```

In [exercise 50](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html), he says to start the program from the project's top level directory like this:

> $ python bin/app.py

Afterwards stating that you start it from the top level directory so the script can access other resources in the project.

But I can't seem to import modules that are in the data folder from app.py. Am I misunderstanding how to setup the directory structure?

Edit: Here's the bare-bones setup I have to try and figure this out

In app.py I have:

```
import data.foobar
```

I have __init__.py in the data directory and foobar.py just contains some nonsense like:

```
class Test:
    x = 0
```

The directory structure matches that of above.

Comment: Can you show how you're using the `import` statements?

Comment: I'll add exactly what I'm doing in an edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exercise asks to do, but your top-level directory needs to be in the PYTHONPATH. Try:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
$ python bin/app.py
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I'm going to leave it unaccepted for now to see if I can find where I went wrong in the exercise. I can't for the life of me remember any mention of changing the path.

Comment: Nevermind, he does mention having to change the the path but not until a later exercise.